# Handling Range content requests of a file with Java Servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, range

I have a Java Servlet that loads File objects from the filesystem and serves them to a client-side javascript web player. Those files are video/mp4 type. When the web client-side javascript player requests a section of the video that is different from the start, it sends a request for partial content to the web server with the header Range. For example

```
 Range: bytes = 500-900/1000
```

How can I properly select the section of the File object corresponding to that range and what headers should I put in my response so as it is valid for use ?

Comment: My answer to this question was deleted by moderator for some reason, but I think the article link it was providing is still relevant: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement HTTP byte-range requests in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427339/how-to-implement-http-byte-range-requests-in-spring-mvc)